# Python pandas: find max values in a cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 dataframes below:

`myEvents`:

```
id    events
1     e1||e2
2     e2
3     e2||e3||e4
```

and the event's end date:

`eventEndDate`:

```
event    endDate
e1       2019-01-26T10:35:47-05:00
e2       2020-01-26T10:05:51-05:00
e3       2020-01-28T10:05:51-05:00
e4       1970-01-01T00:00:00-05:00
```

I'd like to add column in `myEvents` that shows that latest event's end dates, so:

```
id    events      latest_end_date
1     e1||e2      2020-01-26T10:05:51-05:00
2     e2          2020-01-26T10:05:51-05:00
3     e2||e3||e4  2020-01-28T10:05:51-05:00
```

Perhaps the first step would be to read `eventEndDate` to a dictionary, but then how to create a map function to extract the event with max end date in the first dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip the conversion to dict if you are willing to make `event` column in `eventEndDate` the index so you can use `.loc`:

```
eventEndDate.set_index('event', inplace=True)

def find_max_date(events):
    return eventEndDate.loc[events.split('||'), 'endDate'].max()

myEvents['latest_end_data'] = myEvents['events'].apply(find_max_date)
print(myEvents)
```

outputs

```
       events            latest_end_data
0      e1||e2  2020-01-26T10:05:51-05:00
1          e2  2020-01-26T10:05:51-05:00
2  e2||e3||e4  2020-01-28T10:05:51-05:00
```

Answer (score 1):

The map is the right first step. Once you have it, create a UDF that will unpack the events and find the most recent corresponding timestamp.

```
def find_latest_end_date(row):
    end_dates = [eventEndDateDict[event] for event in row['events'].split('||')]
    return max(end_dates)


myEvents['latest_end_date'] = myEvents.apply(find_latest_end_date, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you, can I check if I need to parse the date? or string comparison would suffice? (the date column is of data type String)

Comment: Yes, that date format will sort correctly as string.